# Print with python in tmux via bash

Tags: python, bash, tmux

I am trying to run a python file via bash in a tmux. when i run the python file without the tmux, print functions will print the output.
but when I run it via tmux, nothing is printed.

here is my bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmux new-session -d -s socket 'bash --init-file <(python3 ./foo.py)'
```

this is how i try the python file without tmux:

```
python3 foo.py
```

Comment: `how i try the python file without tmux:` Then why do you do something else in tmux? And where's the closing `'`? Just `tmux .... 'python3 foo.py'` why `bash` and `init-file`?

Comment: Thanks, i forgot to add the `'` to the question.I created this bash file to run it after reboot with cron.

Comment: It is working now, Thank you